# Why do I need to mount a USB flash drive if it's already in my Raspibian

Tags: linux, mount, raspberry-pi

I have been reading tutorials on how to configure transimission to save my downloads  in USB flash drive. When I go to `/media` in my file manager I can see my USB flash drive and access its files. This happens automatically, I didn't mount this device. But all tutorials say I need to mount my flash drive first, and then configure transmission to work with it.

So, if my device already appears in the file manager, isn't it mounted? Do I have to configure something or I should just set `/media/nameOfMyPenDrive` to be the download folder?

Comment: Your distro obviously has automounting capabilities; some do not, hence the advice to mount the drive first... It would probably be a good idea to include the drive in your `/etc/fstab` so that it is mounted on boot.

Comment: So you just need to set the download folder, no need for ant special configuration

Comment: More importantly, probably the drive is NOT mounted until you open some file manager to display available drives. I don't know enough about Raspbian, but for example, Kubuntu automounter does this - there's nothing in /media/ until you open a graphical file manager like Dolphin.

Comment: @SF. excelent comment! So I need to configure the automount, rigth?

Comment: As others suggested, if you want the drive always mounted on startup, just add its entry to fstab, and it will be mounted automatically every time the system starts. Don't confuse **startup automount** (fstab) with the **Automounter** - runtime detector of new drives which mounts them as required. Automounter is a very tricky (and still, good two decades in development, unreliable) thing to configure/modify. If it works, enjoy that it works. If you see contents of the drive, it's (most likely) mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like jasonwryan said, your distro has automounting capabilities. So your USB flash drive is mount already. You just configure your app to download files in "/media/somename" and it is ready.

May be your distro use AutoFs, so you can edit the mount options, if you want. If you use Debian, they should be in "/etc/auto.removable".